# Windows 10 unknown apps just appearing

Tags: windows-10

for some time now I'm getting weird apps running. There is no window of the app or anything, just when I press alt+tab or win+tab I see them as empty tiles. Longer the computer is on, more of these tiles appear. There aren't any processes in task manager that I could kill to delete these tiles. I think that computer is slower due to this and sure consumes more battery.

You can see the picture here: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pv7UG.jpg]

Has anyone seen this problem? Any idea on how to fix it?

Tnx

Comment: Try deleting your history. May be it will work.

Comment: Which history do you mean?

Comment: See if **WinLister** from Nirsoft displays what those window-less programs are.

Comment: It's not showing which programs are :/